# Dynamic disk has fragmented partitions

Tags: windows, dynamic-disk, basic-disk

I want to convert my dynamic disc into basic but my disc disc got fragmented like this(see the image attached)

[image]

Comment: I don't think it "got fragmented" all on its own. You must have set some of the volumes on this disk as RAID-5 mirrored volumes. The choice of the OS you use is also of importance, because as far as I know, recent versions of Windows don't support this kind of setup on a regular PC anymore. They were used in Windows 2003 Server and older versions of Windows (2000, XP), but since Windows 7 and Windows 2008 Server, install only takes place on basic disks, not dynamic ones. If you want to convert your dynamic disk to a basic one, you're going to need a third-party tool.

Comment: I never used RAID-5 mirrored volumes . Do you know how to merge these fragmented partitons . I tried using minitool and EaseUS but no luck

Comment: Well, someone did, and even though the partitions aren't exactly the same size, they seem to content the same amount of data, but that's a moot point. You need to back up all that data somewhere, unless you're prepared to lose all of it. You could use a combination of cloud drives, USB drives, other media such as DVD, what have you, but as harrymc hinted, there's going to be some data loss. Once your data (what you want to save, at least) is backed up somewhere, you can convert your disk from dynamic to basic. Or you can just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while converting a dynamic disk to an basic disk make sure that there is less than two partition (in my case c: and system reserved partition).Then you can use EaseUS or Minitool to convert the disc to basic

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft article
[Change a dynamic disk back to a basic disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk)
advises a conversion method that loses all data, which is the only method possible
with the tools supplied by Microsoft.

If you don't want to lose the data, you need a third-party product.
The problem is that all these products are not freeware.
If you are willing to pay, you may use AOMEI, EaseUS or DiskGenius.

Without paying, all you can do for free is to backup your data (recommended in any case),
convert the disk to Basic with total data-loss, then return the data from backup.

Comment: i  do have mini tool power partion but when i try to convert it says "MiniTcol Partition Wizard cannot convert the specified dynamic disk to
basic disk. Besause MiniTool Partition Wizard can only convert mirrored
volume or simple volume that has only one partition"

Comment: See the article [Fix Partition Wizard Cant Convert Specified Dynamic Disk to Basic](https://www.minitool.com/partition-disk/partition-wizard-cannot-convert-dynamic-to-basic.html). Because the volume contains several segments, you cannot do it from Windows and need to use the [MiniTool Bootable Media](https://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/partition-wizard-bootable.html).

Comment: I did try that but the my main problem is that my disk has fragmented partitons (see the image carefully) My d drive has sub partitions in it (i dont know why or how it happened) can u pls say how to merge them

Comment: The multiple `D:` partitions occur when the dynamic partition is extended. MiniTool will *supposedly* take care of it. In case of failure, I suggest taking before a backup image of the entire disk. For example using [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html). As this is your boot disk, create also its [Bootable Media](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html) and test it, to see if it starts and can see the backup media, for the case of catastrophic error.